# Data adapter "Fill" does not reflect recent adds

Tags: winforms, sql-server-ce

Building a C# WinForms app w/ SQL CE.  I "add" the record using "connected" SQL CE statements but there is a view (using a BindingSource and DataAdapter) that shows the all the client records.  This view does not include the most recent changes.

For example, I add two client records and when I go to the view that uses a dataadapter, these most recent two records don't appear.  If I restart the app, they are there.

How can I get them reflected in the database immediately?

With SQL CE the database - an *.SDF file - is part of the VS solution, in the same directory as the source for the forms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  I found the answer to the question is this thread.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fefef2d3-7674-40f5-87db-729bfea9b14f

Have to set the connection string before calling the Fill method.